# Pandas DateTimeArray How to Get First Element?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas

Given a simple pandas DateTimeArray: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.arrays.DatetimeArray.html

Given a pandas DateTimeArray, dta:

```
dta = pd.array(['2015', '2016'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

How does one get the first element?

Comment: It's working fine for me. What's your version of Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas==1.31.0`, simply slice the array using positional indexing

```py
dta[0]
```

This gives

```py
print(dta[0])
2015-01-01 00:00:00
```

**EDIT**

The input array looks like this

```py
print(dta)
<DatetimeArray>
['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-01-01 00:00:00']
Length: 2, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like any Python array, you can use indexing:

```
dta[0]
```

In cases where this fails, check to see if you really do have an array:

```
print(type(dta))
```

In my case, I actually had a pandas.Series which prompted the original question.

Comment: If you created a pandas `Series` of dates, then you could still use index-based slicing. For example, the `Series` with `pd.Series(pd.date_range('2015', '2016'))` can be sliced using `print(dta[0])` or `print(dta.iloc[0])` to give `2015-01-01 00:00:00`.